# Converting Factor to Date format in R

Tags: r

I am trying to convert a date which is in factor format to the actual date format. Below is the sample data:

```
structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("1-Jun-20", "11-May-20", 
"13-Jul-20", "15-Jun-20", "17-Aug-20", "20-Jul-20", "22-Jun-20", 
"24-Aug-20", "25-May-20", "27-Apr-20", "27-Jul-20", "29-Jun-20", 
"3-Aug-20", "4-May-20", "6-Jul-20"), class = "factor")
```

I tried the below code:

```
open_data$Current_date=as.Date(open_data$Current_date,format = "%Y.%m.%d")
```

However all the date are showing as NA. Could not find a solution for the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use :

```
as.Date(x,format = "%d-%b-%y")
```

Or with `lubridate` :

```
lubridate::dmy(x)
```

Answer (score 0):

We can also use `anydate`

```
library(anytime)
anydate(x)
```